# CloudPebble Crash Logs

Tags: pebble-watch, cloudpebble

I've written a pebble watch face in the CloudPebble IDE. I got a message on the watch that the app had crashed, is there a way to view the crash logs?

In CloudPebble, When I go to Compilation -> View App Logs

I don't see any logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be connected to CloudPebble at the moment of the crash to get any logs. If you are, you should see something like this:

`[INFO    ] E ault_handling.c:68 App fault! {0a7575eb-e5b9-456b-8701-3eacb62d74f1} PC: 0x8019c3d LR: ???
[WARNING ]    Program Counter (PC):  0x8019c3d ???
[WARNING ]      Link Register (LR):        ??? ???`

(This is the raw output - CloudPebble will actually improve this output a little bit and point to the line number if the crash is in your application.)

Comment: Ok, the crash seems to happen at random, so I'm guessing it may be memory related.